# If I have an SAS triangle with two equal sides and an angle of $60^\circ$, would It be correct to reason that the triangle must be equilateral?

Tags: geometry

If I have an SAS triangle with two equal sides and an angle of $60^\circ$, would It be correct to reason that the triangle must be equilateral?

If this reasoning is incorrect then please explain why.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can indeed conclude that the triangle is equilateral.

Recall that the non-vertex angles of an isosceles triangle are necessarily congruent, and that the angles of a triangle sum to $180^\circ$.

Answer (score 0):

If $AB=AC, \angle BAC=60^\circ, \angle ABC= \angle BCA=\dfrac{180^\circ-60^\circ}2=?$

If $AB=AC, \angle ABC=60^\circ,\angle ACB=\angle ABC=?$